# nginx ingress controller の ロードバランサーの挙動(podが一度削除され新しいpodが再登録された場合)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

nginx ingress controller が session affinity(cookie)で load balancing で動作中(たとえば， pod1, pod2, pod3)とします。pod1 が削除され，pod4 が作成され pod2, pod3, pod4 にload balancing される状態になった場合、元々 pod1 に配信されていたセッションを持ったリクエストは、どの pod に割り当てられますか？
・pod1 が削除され，再割り当てされたpodにアクセスし続ける
・pod1 の代わりに作成されたpod4 にアクセス先が変更される
・そのほか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己レスです。以下で、affinity モード(affinity-mode アノーテーション)を設定することで制御可能とありました。
ありがとうございました。

"Setting this to persistent will not rebalance sessions to new servers, therefore providing maximum stickyness."
この値を persistent にすると，新しいサーバにリバランスされません。よって，最大限の stickyness を提供します。

<新しいpodが増えた場合の挙動>
affinity-mode:balanced → リバランスされる可能性アリ
affinity-mode:persistent → はじめに接続したpodに接続し続ける

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#session-affinity